# Insert Layer underneath existing layers in ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer

Given an Existing plot object is it possible to add a layer **UNDERNEATH** an existing layer?

Example, in the graph below, is it possible to add `geom_boxplot()` to `P` such that the boxplot appears **underneath** `geom_point()`?

```
## Starting from: 
library(ggplot2)
P <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=id, y=val)) + geom_point()

## This adds boxplot, but obscures some of the points
P + geom_boxplot()
```

#### Expected Output:

```
# Which is essentially
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=id, y=val)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
## However, this involves re-coding all of P (after the point insertion of the new layer).
##   which is what I am hoping to avoid.
```

[image: Example Output]

---

**Bonus question:**  If there are multiple layers in the existing plot, is it possible to indicate where specifically to insert the new layer (with respect to the existing layers)?

---

#### SAMPLE DATA

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 100
id <- c("A", "B")
dat <- data.frame(id=sample(id, N, TRUE), val=rnorm(N))
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you save the lowest common layer and remix from there.

Comment: @Maiasaura, thanks.  That is what I am doing right now, but the original `P` is rather involved, and I am hoping to avoid recoding it for each small modification I need to produce.

Comment: you can easily change the order of the layers in the final plot, `p2$layers = rev(p2$layers)`

Comment: @baptiste.. I don't want to rev alll of the layers, but thanks for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: you get the idea, it's just a list

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Thanks @baptiste for pointing me in the right direction.  To insert a layer underneath all other layers, just modify the `layers` element of the plot object.

```
## For example:
P$layers <- c(geom_boxplot(), P$layers)
```

---

### Answer to the Bonus Question:

This handy little function inserts a layer at a designated z-level:

```
insertLayer <- function(P, after=0, ...) {
  #  P     : Plot object
  # after  : Position where to insert new layers, relative to existing layers
  #  ...   : additional layers, separated by commas (,) instead of plus sign (+)

      if (after < 0)
        after <- after + length(P$layers)

      if (!length(P$layers))
        P$layers <- list(...)
      else 
        P$layers <- append(P$layers, list(...), after)

      return(P)
    }
```

Comment: Does this work for `theme()` type elements?? (I ask, because simply adding them didn't work, so I wasn't sure if there was a slight variation needed to your approach for those types of element controls)...

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on [Ricardo' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250185/6646912), I use the following snippet:

```
library(ggplot2)

`-.gg` <- function(plot, layer) {
    if (missing(layer)) {
        stop("Cannot use `-.gg()` with a single argument. Did you accidentally put - on a new line?")
    }
    if (!is.ggplot(plot)) {
        stop('Need a plot on the left side')
    }
    plot$layers = c(layer, plot$layers)
    plot
}
```

As it allows you to:

```
P <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=id, y=val)) + geom_point()

P - geom_boxplot()
```

And the boxplot will be placed below the points.