# Insert geom_sf layer underneath existing geom_sf layers

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a basic map of India with states and borders, some labels, and a number of other specifications stored as a gg object. I'd like to generate a number of maps with a district layer, which will bear data from different variables.

To prevent the district maps overwriting state and country borders, it must be before all the previous code, which I'd like to avoid repeating.

I thought I could do this by calling on `$layers` for the gg object as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249653/insert-layer-underneath-existing-layers-in-ggplot2-object). However, it throws an error. Reprex is below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(raster)

# Download district and state data (should be less than 10 Mb in total)

distSF <- st_as_sf(getData("GADM",country="IND",level=2))

stateSF <- st_as_sf(getData("GADM",country="IND",level=1))

# Add border

countryborder <- st_union(stateSF)

# Basic plot

basicIndia <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = stateSF, color = "white", fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = countryborder, color = "blue", fill = NA) +
  theme_dark()

basicIndia
```

[image]

```
# Data-bearing plot

districts <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = distSF, fill = "gold")

basicIndia$layers <- c(geom_sf(data = distSF, fill = "gold"), basicIndia$layers)

basicIndia
#> Error in y$layer_data(plot$data): attempt to apply non-function
```

## Intended outcome

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Why don't you just plot the districts + states + country, since you have 3 separate `sf` objects?

Comment: It could be my own ignorance. I've got a lot of code modifying the look of states and country that won't change and will have to be repeated. That's represented by `basicIndia` in the reprex above. If I do `ggplot(districts) + basicIndia` it throws an error because I'm plotting a gg object, not a df. I don't know how else to store parts of a ggplot to recombine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `geom_sf(data=distSF)` you'll see that it is a list made up of two elements - you want the first one which contains the layer information, so `geom_sf(data = distSF, fill = "gold")[[1]]` should work.

```
districts <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = distSF, fill = "gold")

basicIndia$layers <- c(geom_sf(data = distSF, fill = "gold")[[1]], basicIndia$layers)
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the first stage... i've had to ask a second question though...xD

Answer (score 8):

I'm still not sure if I'm missing a detail of what you're looking for, but `ggplot2` draws layers in the order you provide them. So something like

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(...) +
  geom_line(...)
```

will draw columns, then points on top of those, then lines on top of the previous layers.

Same goes for `sf` plots, which makes it easy to make a plot like this of multiple geographic levels.

(I'm using `rmapshaper::ms_simplify` on the `sf` objects just to simplify them and speed things up for plotting.)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(raster)

distSF <- st_as_sf(getData("GADM",country="IND",level=2)) %>% rmapshaper::ms_simplify()
...
```

Then you can plot by adding up the layers in the order you need them displayed. Keep in mind that if you needed to do other calculations with any of these `sf`s, you could do that in advance or inside your `geom_sf`.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = distSF, fill = "gold", size = 0.1) +
  geom_sf(data = stateSF, color = "white", fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = countryborder, color = "blue", fill = NA)
```

[image]

Regarding trying to add one plot to another: `ggplot2` works in layers, so you create a single base `ggplot` object, then add geometries on top of it. So you could make, for example, two valid plots:

```r
state_plot <- ggplot(stateSF) + 
  geom_sf(color = "white", fill = NA)
country_plot <- ggplot(countryborder) + 
  geom_sf(color = "blue", fill = NA)
```

But you can't add them, because you would have 2 base `ggplot` objects. This should be the error you mentioned:

```r
state_plot + 
  country_plot
#> Error: Don't know how to add country_plot to a plot
```

Instead, if you need to make a plot, then add something else on top of it, make the base `ggplot`, then add geometry layers, such as a `geom_sf` with a different set of data.

```r
state_plot +
  geom_sf(data = countryborder, fill = NA, color = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>