# Reorder sf polygons by type in ggplot map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, layer, orders

I'm attempting to plot vector objects from a shp file onto a map, using the sf package and ggplot. Basically: I created a base map of the relevant area (U.S. West Coast), then downloaded the relevant shape file showing Biologically Important Areas (BIAs) for cetaceans (from: https://cetsound.noaa.gov/important). I subsetted the .shp file for the relevant area (U.S. West Coast) and area types (feeding and migration). I reordered the bia_select list so that migration areas would come first. Then I layered BIAs onto the map, colored by type. Here's the code and resulting map.

```
    # useful on MacOS to speed up rendering of geom_sf() objects
    if (!identical(getOption("bitmapType"), "cairo") && isTRUE(capabilities()[["cairo"]])
    {options(bitmapType = "cairo")
        }    
    
     #base map
    boundaries <- data.frame(x1 = c(-125.5, -125.5, -125.5), y1 = c(34.448, 36.306, 37.948), x2 = c(-120.472, -121.901, -122.785), y2 = c(34.448, 36.306, 37.948))#create gridpoints for regional boundaries
    
    states <- sf::st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))#state lines and coast
    CAfromstates <- states %>%
      subset(., states$ID == "california")
    
    world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")#national boundaries

    #import data
            biaf <- st_read("/Users/elizaoldach/Desktop/CetMap_BIA_WGS84-1/CetMap_BIA_WGS84.shp")
        
    #select geography and area types
    bia_select <- biaf  %>%
      filter(region %in% c("West Coast"),
             BIA_type %in% c("Feeding", "Migration"))

   #reorder features so migration comes first  
   bia_select_ordered <- bia_select[order(bia_select$OBJECTID, decreasing=FALSE),]

    #choose colors
    bia_colors <- c("plum2", "#CAB7A500")
    
    #create map
    map3 <- ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = world, fill = "#CAB7A5") +
      geom_sf(data = states, fill = "#CAB7A5") +
      geom_sf(data = bia_select_ordered, alpha=0.5, aes(fill=BIA_type)) +
      scale_color_manual(values=bia_colors)+
      labs(fill="BIA Type")+
      coord_sf(
        xlim = c(-130,-108),
        ylim = c(22, 51),
        expand = FALSE
      )+
      theme_classic()
    map3
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOGBg.jpg)

The problem with this map is that migration areas (blue, larger) have been plotted on top of feeding areas (pink, smaller). I'd like to plot this so that feeding areas are on top. Reordering the list so that migration areas came first did not help. I think it must be relatively simple but I haven't been able to crack this! Does anyone have advice?

Comment: I haven't tried downloading your data & runnning your code, but it seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53036873/5325862

Comment: hhhmmm ... typically it is the other way round in ggplot. In ggplot_2. 2.0, fill order is based on the order of the factor levels. The default order will plot the first level at the top of the stack instead of the bottom. If you want the first level at the bottom of the stack you can use reverse = TRUE. If all fails, you can create 2 separate data sets, i.e. `filter()` your data and supply the sub-data sets to 2 different `geom_sf()` layers. Note you have to order the factor levels not the dataset (ggplot will always use the default ordering irrespective of what you see).

Comment: Thank you @camille - the difference that I can see is that the linked post is plotting separate sf objects, versus this question which is categories within the same object. I could split this into separate objects but this seems easier for creating the legend.

Comment: And thanks @Ray, I think that issue-- ordering the factor levels, not the dataset-- is a key issue I was facing.

Comment: Cool. Great to see that you got it fixed. I regularly struggle with ggplot's default ordering. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. The problem seems to be that BIA_type was still a character, so reordering didn't work. This was an easy fix:

```
#check class of variable    
class(bia_select$BIA_type) 

#BIA_type is character, change to factor and specify levels 
bia_select$BIA_type<-factor(bia_select$BIA_type, levels=c("Migration","Feeding"))
```

With that, I was able to rerun the ggplot code and end up with a map where feeding areas are on top of migration areas.